# Fourier transform of derivative of plane wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fourier-transform, mathematics

What is the Fourier transform $F(k)$ of:

$$ f(y) = A \, ik \, e^{iky} $$

If you calculate it with Wolfram Alpha, it says that there are no results found in terms of standard functions.

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Wolfram Alpha is correct here. That Fourier transform doesn't exist as a standard function, but it does exist as a distribution - it's the distributional derivative of the Dirac delta.

Distributions are basically functionals, i.e. they're objects $\mathcal D$ which take a ("test") function $\varphi\in L_2(\mathbb R)$, say, and give a number $\mathcal D[\varphi] \in \mathbb C$. The Dirac delta is such one such distribution, and it is defined as
$$
\delta[\varphi] = \varphi[0].
$$
The distributional derivative is defined via a simple formula - you just defined as
$$
\delta'[\varphi] = -\varphi'(0),
$$
i.e., where the Dirac delta returns the value of what it's "integrated" against at the origin, the Dirac-delta's distributional derivative returns the value of the derivative of its argument at the origin.

The origin for that identification comes from the heuristic that if you integrate by parts you should be able to get
\begin{align}
\delta'[\varphi]
& = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x) \varphi(x) \mathrm dx
\\ & = \left[\delta'(x) \varphi(x) \right]_{-\infty}^\infty - \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x) \varphi'(x) \mathrm dx
\\ & = -\varphi'(0),
\end{align}
with the boundary terms vanishing because $\varphi(x)$ should vanish at infinity. (This is obviously a shaky argument and it only works as a heuristic - if you want to make it work rigorously, you need to start with distribution theory from the beginning.)

Comment: I am not that familiar with distributional derivatives. Is there a way to write the Fourier transform as distributions then?

Comment: @FredericVanderveken See edited answer. To be honest, if you want any more detail, you really do need to start from the beginning. But as a start to your specific question - no, the Fourier transform isn't a distribution, but you *can* (sometimes) calculate the Fourier transform of a distribution, which will generally be another distribution.

Comment: Okay, you said that the Fourier transform of my function the distributional derivative of the Dirac delta is. So, then it becomes: $$ F(k) = -f'(0) = Ak^2 $$ Is this correct?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood the role of $f$ in this answer - the formula you wrote down is basically gibberish. Your question is pretty messy, and it admits two distinct interpretations, which are basically $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ik e^{iky} \mathrm dy = ik \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{iky} \mathrm dy = ik \delta(k)\equiv 0$$ and $$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty ik e^{iky} \mathrm dk = \delta'(y).$$ But seriously, there is no way to understand this without a solid foundation (starting from the very fundamentals) on distribution theory.

Comment: This is the one that I am looking for: $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ike^{iky} e^{-2\pi iky} \text{d}y = ? $$

Comment: @FredericVanderveken That just looks like you're incorrectly mixing and matching between different conventions - it looks like you've made a mistake upstream of there. The appearance of $iky$ and $2\pi i k y$ in two different exponents is a massive red flag, and the chances of it appearing naturally are basically negligible.

Comment: But still, as you've written it: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ike^{iky} e^{-2\pi iky} \mathrm{d}y = ik \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i(2\pi-1)ky}\mathrm{d}y = ik \, \delta((2\pi-1)k) \equiv 0.$$ If that's not what you were expecting, then I'm sorry, but this is where I get off the bus - chat is not for extended back-and-forth. Take it to chat instead.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it now! Thank you for the answers.